# How to test service using library that uses its own XMLHttpRequest instead of $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I got an angular service look like

```js
function userService() {
  // A library provide methods that not used $http service and not $.ajax either
  this.lib = theLib;

  // This one will invoke "api/v1/user"
  this.getAllUser = function () {
     return lib.getAll();
  }
}
```

How can I test these functions below

```js
it('should return all user', function () {
   // How can I mock the returned data without using $http
   userService.getAllUser();
})
```

It could have been easy if it used $http or $ajax instead so that I can mock use `$httpBackend` or mock ajax's return. There's another way to mock the `theLib` but it has many methods inside but I don't think that's a good idea. Any suggestions in this case?

Comment: You can try to use [xhr-mock](https://github.com/jameslnewell/xhr-mock)

Comment: Thanks @jcubic. I will try.

Comment: It really depends, what is the level of testing you are aiming at. If you are interested in unit testing (i.e. service itself) then you should mock the library, not the communication provider.

Comment: @VladimirM I think it's better to mock XHR instead the lib instead. As I said it's designed with many levels inside. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Jasmine 2.0, a new API for testing ajax  has been introduced.

[Here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html) is the link for that

You can do some thing like this, set up the stib ajax before each test and uninstall it in  after each, you can refer to the link above for more information

```
beforeEach(function() {
  jasmine.Ajax.install();
  jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('YOUR_URL_HERE').andReturn({
    responseText: 'YOUR_RAW_STUBBED_DATA_HERE'
  });
});

afterEach(function() {
 jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
});

it('My Ajax Test', function() {
 // . . . code that makes an ajax request . . .
})
```

For XHR request you can try something like this

```
beforeEach(function() {
 // spyOn(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'open').andCallThrough(); // Jasmine 1.x
  spyOn(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'open').and.callThrough(); // Jasmine 2.x
  spyOn(XMLHttpRequest.prototype, 'send');
});

 it("should return all user", function() {
    userService.getAllUser();
    expect(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But in this case, the lib doesn't use ajax so it's not useful to mock the ajax.